# Where are further water sources in Project Zomboid?

Tags: project-zomboid

Are there any permanent water sources once the water supply is switched off?

So far I have only found one well on the isolated farm far in the north-west.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a second well somewhere in the world, but other than wells, there are no permanent water sources.

You can, at carpentry level 3, build rain collector barrels and collect water from them after it rains.

Comment: Carpentry 3-4 for rain collectors

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my comment. I think one of the patches in the last 2 years upped the level of carpenty required from 2 to 3-4.

Comment: No probs. I actually wasnt sure myself, was it 3 or 4 :). BTW, would be helpful to mention game Version in reply

Answer (score 2):

Permanent sources of water are:

1. River/lake - Requires cooking the water.
2. Rainwater - Use rain collectors or pots placed on the ground. Not completely reliable as it requires rain so make sure you collect enough when it does rain.
3. Wells - If you can find one and to help with that you can check this [map](https://map.projectzomboid.com/).

Answer (score 1):

### River

Use "Cabin in the woods" for base and you will not be influenced by water supply switch-off.